# sequence with min & max numbers

Tags: c#, sequence

I'm trying to get this program to let me enter a desired number(entries), then enter a desired value to this entries. It should write out the biggest value(green), smallest(red) then the rest of the sequence. And in the next row, biggest and smallest should change places(didn't even type code for this). What am I doing wrong(especially in the last 'for loop' )

```
        int max = int.MinValue;
        int min = int.MaxValue;

        Console.WriteLine("How many numbers do you want to enter ?  ");
        int kolicinaBrojeva = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] niz = new int[kolicinaBrojeva];

        for (int i = 0; i < kolicinaBrojeva; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter {0}. a number:", i + 1);
            niz[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (niz[i] > max)
            {
                max = niz[i];
            }

            if (niz[i] < min)
            {
                min = niz[i];
            }
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(max + ", ");
        Console.ResetColor();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(min + ", ");
        Console.ResetColor();

        for (int i = 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (niz[i] < max && niz[i] > min)
            {
                Console.Write(niz[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: "And in the next row" what next row?

Comment: Provide a sample for what you want. If `1,2,3,4` is the original input, Then should first row be: `4,1,2,3` and second row be : `1,4,2,3`??

Comment: It is usually easier for the user to enter all the numbers in one line, separated by space or comma, and the program to figure out how many and to parse the values. See `parts=line.Split(',');`

Comment: @jafar , yes that's how the result shoud be, or 'max;sequnece;min' and next row 'min;sequnece;max'.  Sorry if it wasnt clear enough, should've print it.

Answer (score 2):

The last for loop should be like below:

```
    for (int i = kolicinaBrojeva - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (niz[i] < max && niz[i] > min)
        {
            Console.Write(niz[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will read in kolicinaBrojeva numbers correctly, but min and max will not be set correctly. No other int is greater than int.MaxValue and similarly, no other int is less than int.MinValue. You could do the following instead:

```
int max = int.MinValue;
int min = int.MaxValue;
```

With this, you'll get the correct min and max, however, I'm not sure of what you're trying to do in the last loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] temp = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        int[] numbers = new int[temp.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
             numbers[i] = int.Parse(temp[i]);

        int minIndex = 0;
        int maxIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] < numbers[minIndex])
                minIndex = i;
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[maxIndex])
                maxIndex = i;
        }

        Swap(ref numbers[maxIndex], ref numbers[0]);
        Swap(ref numbers[minIndex], ref numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
        Print(numbers, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Red);

        Swap(ref numbers[0], ref numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
        Print(numbers, ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Green);
    }

    static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    static void Print(int[] array, ConsoleColor a, ConsoleColor b)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = a;
        Console.Write(array[0] + "  ");
        Console.ResetColor();
        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
            Console.Write(array[i] + "  ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = b;
        Console.WriteLine(array[array.Length - 1]);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```